# Lock the orientation of ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have app that supports all kind of orientations, however i want certain viewControllers to support only landscape and few to lock on Potrait Mode.
How can i do that, I have tried below code but nothing works.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
// pre-iOS 6 support
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: what is not working? with the code you posted, does the controller rotate landscape? how are the different controllers you mention connected?

Comment: by navigation controllers. The controller does rotate to landscape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All view controllers pushed on to the same navigation controller must support the same orientation. Specifically, I believe that only the root view controller `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is ever taken into account. You can have a look at [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601983/navigationcontroller-pushed-viewcontrollers-wont-autorotate) for a sort of workaround; or at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196758/selective-autorotation-within-a-uinavigationcontroller-and-uitabbarcontroller) for a different approach that could be of help.

The second post I linked above suggests using this definition for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` you might tweak it for your case:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
  {   
  if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UIViewController *rootController = [((UINavigationController *)self.selectedViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    return [rootController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
  }
  return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
```